# Castor JAXB swaRef limitation

Tags: xsd, jaxb, castor

We are using Castor for marshalling/unmarhalling xsd:s. We are using attachments and refering to the with the "swaRef" element. According to this page Castor does not support this, http://docs.codehaus.org/display/CASTOR/Castor+JAXB:

> Some of the functionality could require to be actually implemented in
>   backing Castor     framework - for example handling the attachment
>   through MTOM/XOP and swaRef.

How can we overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

My recommendation would be to use a standard [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation that supports everything you need (models generated from XML schema, swaref, etc) rather than implementing some workaround to use Castor.  An implementation is included in the JDK/JRE as of Java SE 6, and other implementations (such as MOXy) are also available.

**Note**

Based on the [**link you provided**](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/CASTOR/Castor+JAXB) it does not appear as though Castor has run the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) compliance tests and in the  "Functional testing" section on that page it appears as though Castor has not fully tested its support for the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) annotations.

> **Functional testing**
>
> I think a little bit of time should be spend on
>   functional testing, and this might get quite tedious. Looking, for
>   example, at the @XmlAttribute annotation, there's a lot of variants to
>   test, requiring POJOs to be annotated slightly different for each test
>   case. That would require us to write a lot of POJOs and wire them up
>   accordingly in the test classes. Let's see whether we can agree on how
>   to go about this (layout, package structures, ...).

Comment: Thanks Blaise, I appreciate your answer. We come from a large legacy project so moving to JAXB would be a big leap, but we'll see... I am still surprised of this Castor limitation since to my understanding, Castor is quite a popular tool.